# How do I manipulate the HTML of a WebView in Android?

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to read in a website (XML/XSLT), and change the theme to one that I've created so that it looks better on the web. The site currently is horribly formatted for mobile devices, and i want to fix that. :) Is this possible? If so, how?

So far I've got my app loading the website:

```
WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        activity.setTitle("Loading...");
        activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
        if (progress == 100)
            activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }
});
view.setWebViewClient(new MyViewerClient());
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view.loadUrl("http://www.somewebsite.com");
```

Now i'm looking for something like:

```
String html = view.getHTML();  //  <---- does a function like this exist?
html = myparser(html); // parse html and change out xsl theme
view.loadData(html); // set html back and continue on
```

Side info: this site has a login (SSL), and uses cookies (haven't got there yet but don't want to corner myself with a solution that won't work in those instances)

Answer (score 0):

Few things, firstly, if you have access to the server side code, you might want to make changes there so that the web site looks better on mobile devices, intact devices of may different sizes. This is a very common problem nowadays and I believe the recommended solution is to use different `css` files to theme your website appropriately for different screen sizes.

Now if you can't or don't have access to server side code, then we have a problem. You'll really have to reverse engineer the site/page's code and strip out the pieces of html/css that are not of interest on a smaller device. Note that this will not reduce the traffic as you'd still need to get all of the page locally and then make a pass to strip out the unneeded pieces and insert new ones.

If you favor the second approach, know that it is going to be brittle. Any changes to the web site and boom, your application would stop working as expected. If you still insist, then search for ways to perform html parsing on the android. I know there are several xml parsers, but I'm not sure about html.

Comment: Yea, the second option is the way I have to go because I don't own the page. There isn't going to be much manipulation to the page except for me essentially swapping out the stylesheet. That's not the hard part. What i don't know is how to retrieve the HTML that the WebView pulled.